# pytelegrambotapi - can't access "from" property due to it being keyword

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to access `message.reply_to_message.from` but in VS Code it highlights in yellow, I can't compile it. When using `['from']` it says this:

```
TypeError: 'Message' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I access "from"?

```
message.reply_to_message.from.username
```

Comment: python has no compiler, what do you mean by compile? Can you provide a snippet of what you are trying to run?

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't name functions or classes/class members after keywords and builtins.

Comment: @Cr4zyTun4 i mean its not even running if i use from property

Comment: Can you help me to understand what is that you are trying to do? Link to documentation, what is this message object you are trying to access, why you are trying to access it and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the tag and found the documentation on google.
When you having this kind of problems always refer to the doc.
[Here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html) there are listed all the properties of the message object.

There you can read:

> In Python from is a reserved word, use from_user instead.

*From_user* from the doc is the following:

> Sender of the message; empty for messages sent to channels. For
> backward compatibility, this will contain a fake sender user in
> non-channel chats, if the message was sent on behalf of a chat.

Try to replace *from* with *from_user*

Comment: "Try to replace user with from_user" should be "Try to replace frome with from_user"